# Hint: Approach for the solution of the following three equations

Tags: linear-algebra

The equations are (with $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$):

\begin{align}a^n &= 729\\[0.1cm] a^{n-1}nb &= 7290 \\[0.1cm] n(n-1)a^{n-2}b^2 &= 60750\end{align}

I've tried several approaches such as substituting $a = \frac{nb}{10}$ but i can't seem to make it work. Please provide only a hint, and not the complete solution.

Edit: I'm trying to solve the above equations for finding out the values of $a$, $b$ and $n$ in the expansion of $(a+b)^n$ when the first three terms are $729$, $7290$ and $30375$.

Comment: What are $a,b,n$? Real numbers? Fractions? Integers? Natural numbers?

Comment: n is natural. a and b are real. Edit: since the first and second terms are both expansions and are both positive, we can also conclude that a and b are positive.

Comment: Do you wish to find all solutions or just one?

Comment: According to the book, there is only one solution. Please see the clarification i added to the bottom for some clarification of the purpose.

Comment: I have $n=12/7$ are you sure about your equations?

Comment: @N74 I triple checked them but i could have made an error. I provided a justification for the 3 equations in an edit to my post.

Comment: Oops, looks like i did make an error in the last equation. Correcting now.

Comment: ok.. now $n=6$... correct also the numbers in the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that each equation looks much like the previous one (since you are expanding the binomial coefficient): 
\begin{align}a^n&=729\\[0.14cm]a^n(a^{-1}nb)&=729\cdot10\\a^n(a^{-1}nb)(a^{-1}(n-1)b)&=729\cdot10\cdot\frac{25}{3}\end{align} where the last one may also be rewritten as (ok, since you asked only for a hint, this is becoming a spoiler)

> $$a^n(a^{-1}nb)(a^{-1}nb-a^{-1}b)=729\cdot10\cdot\left(10-\frac{5}{3}\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** You can find $n$ using values of $\dfrac{nb}{a}$ and $\dfrac{(n-1)b}{a}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.**

We know $$a^n=729^1=3^6=9^3=27^2$$

Answer (score 1):

Divide the second one by the first one: $nb=10a$.

Divide the third one by the second one: $(n-1)b=\frac{25}{3}a$.

Subtract them: $b=\frac{5}{3}a$.

So we get $n\frac{5}{3}a=10a$, hence $n=6$.

Pretty easy to find $a$ and $b$ now.